# How call o specific slot with signals.boostv2

Tags: c++, boost

I have worked on an application which is depend on publisher subscriber (using boost.signalsv2)

here is controller;

```
#include "view.hpp"
class Controller
{
    boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;
public:
    Controller() {
    }

    void subscribe(listener& listener) {
        // Signal with no arguments and a void return value
        sig.connect(boost::bind(&listener::OnUpdate, &listener));
    }

    void DoWork() const {
        // Call all of the slots
        sig();
    }




    void Update();
};
```

doWork function call all subscring slots.

```
int main() {
    Controller c;

    View l1, l2;

    c.subscribe(l1);

    std::cout << "One subscribed:\n";
    c.DoWork();

    c.subscribe(l2);
    c.subscribe(l3);
    std::cout << "\nBoth subscribed:\n";
    c.DoWork();
}
```

There are more than one subscriber systems.(l1 ,l2 and l3) 
I want to publish specific one (l2)  How can i check and do this?

Answer (score 2):

That's not how it's intended. If you want to distinguish, either have different signals OR pass a token to the handlers that makes it possible for them to know whether they're interested in that particular event.

If you want to have a specific /position/ in the list of connected handlers to take the event, then you may be able to use an alternative/custom combiners: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/signals2/thread-safety.html#id-1.3.36.7.3